# Corrupt values when writing and reading from the same RWTexture2D in HLSL/DirectX?

Tags: shader, texture, hlsl, directx12, memory

I'm playing around with DirectX 12 ray tracing, and I'm  trying to read and write data to a 32-bit RGBA floating point RWTexture2DArray within a DirectX 12 HLSL shader. I'm getting weird corruption/noise when I read back values I've written to the texture.

I've bound the texture as a UAV, and in my shader I've tagged it with the "globallycoherent" like so:

```
globallycoherent RWTexture2DArray<float4>   myTextureArray;
```

I'm able to demonstrate the issue I'm seeing with a trivial bit of shader code:

```
myTextureArray[xIndex, yIndex, 0] = float4((float)xIndex / (float)xRes, (float)yIndex / (float)yRes, 0.0f, 1.0f);

myOutputTexture[xIndex, yIndex] = myTextureArray[xIndex, yIndex, 0];
```

For the sake of a simple demonstration, I'm just writing increasing values of red along the x axis, and increasing values of green along the y axis, and storing them into the first slice of my 32-bit floating point RGBA RWTexture2DArray. Then, I'm immediately reading the values back from the same position.

Unfortunately, even with this trivial bit of code, when I read the values back they're often garbled. I've got a screenshot of the results, notice the weird, speckled noise in the output:

[image: Notice the weird noise?d]

I'm relatively new to DirectX12/HLSL, and I have a feeling I'm likely missing something simple. I've consulted [the Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/sm5-object-rwtexture2darray), which states you can both read and write to a RWTexture2DArray, and I'm using the "globallycoherent" prefix as instructed.

I'm using NVidia Falcor as a wrapper for some DXR experiments, so it's possible either I've missed some specific configuration (or, there's a bug in their implementation). If you can think of anything I might have missed, or might not be understanding, I'd be very appreciative of your help! I'm trying to use an array of textures as a buffer to hold various data elements (positions, indexes, etc etc), so if there's an easier/better way, let me know!